# Grouping country polygons into a region without dissolving borders

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-plugins, region

PowerBI allows for the import of a shapefile via JSON to create a map for data visualization.

In PowerBI, I want my users to be able to select *either* a single country *or* a region that contains that country.

As far as I can see, my process in QGIS should be:

1. Create a shapefile with all country polygons
2. Create a shapefile in which I group the country polygons into regions and delete polygons outside the regions
3. Merge the two shapefiles
4. Convert to JSON

If this process is correct (please tell me if there is a better way!), my problem is that using Merge Selected Features deletes the borders between the countries in the region, resulting in a very politically incorrect map!

[image: politically incorrect map]

Is there a way to group country polygons into a region without deleting borders?

Comment: Thanks guys. Have applied Kadir's recommendation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to take a look at `Collect Geometries` tool. You can extract selected features as one geometry without loosing the boundaries by means of the tool. You can also group countries belonging to the same region without deleting the borders by specifying `Unique ID fields` (in your case it means region column).

[image]